# PNG do not load when using webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack.

PNG files are failed to load in my project, Some of the SlickGrid plugin uses url() function to load PNG files as given below,

[image]

But I'm getting following error on my browser console,
[image]

Here is my webpack file,

```
/* eslint-env node */

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/xyz/static',
  entry: {
    reactComponents: './bundle/components.js',
    history: './js/history/index.js',
    slickgrid: './bundle/slickgrid.js',
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'amd',
    path: __dirname + '/xyz/static/js/generated',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /vendor/],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader'],
    }],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of a `url-loader` in your webpack config to load images like

```
 module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /vendor/],
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader'],
    },{
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
            use:['url-loader']
        }],
  }
```

and then in your code you can import images like

```
import img from 'path/to/image.png';
```

and use it as a source in the image tag like

```
<img src={img} />
```

Comment: SlickGrid is 3rd party library, Why do I need to change its code?

Comment: Dont' change its code, however I suppose webpack config is your file, so can try to change it

Comment: Sorry, I am new to webpack, I do not understand your last sentence 'and use it as a source in the image tag'

Comment: Check the update, however you may not need it if you are using a 3rd Party file. But you sure need to add an image loader in webpack config `{
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
            use:['url-loader']
        }`

Comment: I tried, but getting the same error :(
I added url_loader in webpack config then I ran - yard add url-loader && yarn install && yarn run build